Can't get input to update with observeEvent and actionButton in shiny
I have a shiny app that works and I want to make the functions into modules to clean up the app.R script to make it easier to read for others.
I am stuck on trying to convert a block of code which is related to costs. Below is a reproducible example. The code I have commented out works but as you can see I want to write a function for it instead so it is easier to read. As it currently stands with the code commented out, it will run and not produce any errors but won't update the costs for Cost1, Cost2, or Cost3. I have searched almost every other question on here including link1, link2, link3, link4 and link5 but I can't any of them to work for me.
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(2, actionButton("UpdateButton1", "UpdateButton1")),
    column(2, actionButton("UpdateButton2", "UpdateButton2")),
    column(2, actionButton("UpdateButton3", "UpdateButton3")),
    
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 numericInput("Cost1", "Cost 1", value = 10, min = 0),
                 numericInput("Cost2", "Cost 2", value = 20, min = 0),
                 numericInput("Cost3", "Cost 3", value = 30, min = 0)
          )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
#  
#   observeEvent(input$UpdateButton1, {
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost1", value = 100)
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost2", value = 100)
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost3", value = 100)
# 
#   })
#   
#   observeEvent(input$UpdateButton2, {
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost1", value = 200)
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost2", value = 200)
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost3", value = 200)
#     
#   })
#   
#   observeEvent(input$UpdateButton3, {
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost1", value = 300)
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost2", value = 300)
#     updateNumericInput(inputId = "Cost3", value = 300)
#   })
# 
# }

###The above works but I want to make it cleaner because I have a lot more costs so I wrote a function but it doesn't work:

update_costs_button1 <- function(id, Cost1, Cost2, Cost3){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    updateNumericInput(inputId = Cost1, value = 100)
    updateNumericInput(inputId = Cost2, value = 100)
    updateNumericInput(inputId = Cost3, value = 100)
  })
}


observeEvent(input$UpdateButton1, {
  update_costs_button1("id1", "Cost1", "Cost2", "Cost3")
})

}
shinyApp(ui, server)


Add session and it works.  Try this
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(2, actionButton("UpdateButton1", "UpdateButton1")),
    column(2, actionButton("UpdateButton2", "UpdateButton2")),
    column(2, actionButton("UpdateButton3", "UpdateButton3")),
    
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           numericInput("Cost1", "Cost 1", value = 10, min = 0),
           numericInput("Cost2", "Cost 2", value = 20, min = 0),
           numericInput("Cost3", "Cost 3", value = 30, min = 0)
    )
  )
)

update_costs_button1 <- function(id, mysession, Cost1, Cost2, Cost3){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    updateNumericInput(mysession, inputId = Cost1, value = 100)
    updateNumericInput(mysession, inputId = Cost2, value = 200)
    updateNumericInput(mysession, inputId = Cost3, value = 300)
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$UpdateButton1, {
    update_costs_button1("id1", session, "Cost1", "Cost2", "Cost3")
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)


Perfect, thank you. Is there a reason you moved that function to the UI? I had it in the server. I will move it to it's own script anyway but just out of interest, was there any reason you moved it out of the server?

As a module function, you want it outside of ui and server.
